# m2e not integrated in Eclipse Luna

Tags: eclipse, macos, maven, m2e, eclipse-luna

I installed m2e plugin in eclipse luna, but I got this error whenever I try to create new maven project or navigate Maven section from eclipse preferences.
Screenshot is attached here.[image]

Please help me to run maven in eclipse. I'm running eclipse on Mac OSX 10.10.2.

Comment: Look in the .log file in the workspace .metadata folder to see if there is a more detailed message about this

Comment: !MESSAGE Unhandled event loop exception
!STACK 0
java.lang.NullPointerException
        at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.debug.ui.jres.BuildJREDescriptor.getDescription(BuildJREDescriptor.java:26)

I found exceptions like this.

Comment: Sounds similar to bug [419577](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=419577) - check that you have a default JRE/JDK selected in Preferences > Java > Installed JREs.

Comment: I have Java 6 and Java 8 both installed in my system. I'm currently checking Java 6 manually by giving path: /System/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0.jdk/Contents/Home

Comment: This is strange because line 26 in BuildJREDescriptor in Eclipse Luna 4.4.2 is not a code line and cannot produce a NullPointerException.

Comment: I had Eclipse from Google (bundled as Android Developer Tools), I recently upgraded the eclipse to luna. Can this be the problem then?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/73060/discussion-between-dg-no-9-and-greg-449).